# Soap UI 5.5 doesnt open in mac

Tags: soapui

I started having these issues about a month back. My SOAPUI wouldnt open in my mac. I have tried all sorts of things from changing jre versions, fixes in info.plist file, changing vmoptions etc etc but none seem to work. I have uninstalled atleast 20 times and tried even older versions. Everytime I start, this is the error message I get

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.normalize(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.getRoot(DefaultSoapUICore.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.loadExternalLibraries(DefaultSoapUICore.java:511)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.init(DefaultSoapUICore.java:140)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.(DefaultSoapUICore.java:126)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.createDefault(DefaultSoapUICore.java:105)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.getSettings(SoapUI.java:1699)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI$SoapUIRunner.run(SoapUI.java:792)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Can someone help????

Thanks,
Ram